# How to set the css property of dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using javascript to write some content in a div tag. The data is received through ajax.
Here is the script

```
 $.ajax({
            url :' the url',
            data : {
                productValue: selectedText,
                giveMyId : saveMyName
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                var imageHTML='';
                var dataLength=data.length;
                photosHasPath=data[0];
                if(dataLength > 1)
                {
                for(var i=1;i<dataLength;i++)
                {
                    allProductNames.push(data[i]);
                   imageHTML += '<img src="' + photosHasPath + data[i] + '" height="100" width="100" style="padding: 0.5em;">' + 
                          ' <input type=\"button\" class=\"deletePhoto\" value=\"Delete\" name=\"'+data[i]+'\">';
                }
                $('#pastePhotos').html(imageHTML);
            }
            else
            {
              $('#pastePhotos').html('<i>No photos left.</i>');  
            }

            }
        });
```

Now I am trying to set the css property of this div (having id 'pastePhotos') which is **display:inline-table**. But its not working. Its showing the images and the delete button like a text in a single line.
**Question:-**
 SO how can i set the css property for it?
**Note:-**
I have already tried the following things
1 .

```
 imageHTML += '<img src="' + photosHasPath + data[i] + '" height="100" width="100" style="padding: 0.5em; display: inline-table;">' + 

' <input type=\"button\" class=\"deletePhoto\" value=\"Delete\" name=\"'+data[i]+'\">';
```

2 . `'<div style="display: inline-table;">' + imageHtml + '</div>'`

3 . `<div id="pastePhotos" style="display: inline-table;">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to put the styles inline in the Javascript code. Since you have already given an `id`, you can simply add the styles in a CSS file or `style` element

```css
#pastePhotos {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

However, the main problem seems to be missing style for the `img` and `input` elements. For this, you must add a

```css
#pastePhotos img, #pastePhotos input {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

and wrap them in an additional `div` for the `table-row`

```js
imageHTML += '<div class="img-row"><img src="' + photosHasPath + data[i] + '" height="100" width="100" style="padding: 0.5em;">' + 
          ' <input type=\"button\" class=\"deletePhoto\" value=\"Delete\" name=\"'+data[i]+'\"></div>';
```

```css
#pastePhotos .img-row {
    display: table-row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use jquery to directly add css attributes

As in `$('#pastePhotos').css (propertyName, value )`

http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

or if you have your attributes as a style class you can also use jquery to add this class

```
$('#pastePhotos').addClass( "myStyle" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `complete: function(){}` block in the `$.ajax({})`. Then add css using javascript by`$('#pastePhotos').css("display", 'inline-table')` and so on with in that `complete` block.